# Discrete Lyapunov Equation with commuting solution

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

For a real matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$, with eigenvalues $0 < | \lambda_i | < 1$ and matrix $B$ of size $n \times m$ with $m \leq n$ of rank $m$, there exists a unique definite solution $X$ to the discrete Lyapunov equation
$$
A X A^T + B B^T = X.
$$
If now $AX = XA$, then
$$
A A^T - I = B B^T X^{-1}.
$$
Under which condition is $B^T X^{-1} = \alpha B^T$ for some scalar $\alpha$?

For $m = 1$, $B B^T$ is rank 1. As the left side is symmetric, I believe that in that case, it is always $B B^T X^{-1} = \alpha B B^T$. Is that true also for the general $m$?

Comment: $XAA^T - X = -BB^T$. We get $X=BB^T(I-AA^T)^{-1}$. Obvious,  left hand side diagonal if right hand side is diagonal.

Comment: @NeitherNor Yes, but $I - AA^T$ is not necessarily invertible. In particular, I'm interested in the case $m = 1$ such that it is definitely not invertible.

Comment: What has the size of $B$ to do with the question if $I-AA^T$ is invertible? Let us look when $det(I-AA^T)$ is zero. This is when 1 is a eigenvalue of $AA^T$. $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$. What can you then say about the max eigenvalue of $AA^T$ if the max eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are both smaller 1?

Comment: @NeitherNor The eigenvalues of $A A^T$ are the singular values of $A$. The max singular values can be larger than the max eigenvalue, although limited by [Weyl's theorem][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_in_matrix_theory].

Comment: For $m=1$ isn't it also imply $AA^T-I$ is rank 1? Also I didn't get why you are searching for $B^T X^{-1} = \alpha B^T$.